# I would like to add char Z when looping through, to one of column in the array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, foreach

I would like to add char Z when looping through, to one of column in the array.

**My result is:**

```
A B C c
D E F f 
G H I 
J K L
```

**but I want to:**

```
A B* C c 
D E* F f 
G H* I 
J K* L
```

**Here is my code:**

```
       char z = '*';

        char[][] marks = {
                {'A', 'B', 'C', 'c'},
                {'D', 'E', 'F','f'},
                {'G', 'H', 'I'},
                {'J', 'K', 'L'},
        };
        for (char[] x : marks) {
            for (char y : x) {
                System.out.print(y + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
          }
```

Comment: instead of an enhanced for loop, use a for loop with a counter variable in your inner loop. Then simply check if that counter variable is 1 and add "*" to your output in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to keep track of the position where you want to add the z character!
In your example, you're always adding it to the second column so y=1.

An Example would be something like this :

```
     char z = '*';
     char[][] marks = { { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'c' }, { 'D', 'E', 'F', 'f' }, { 'G', 'H', 'I' },
            { 'J', 'K', 'L' }, };
     for ( char[] x : marks) {
        int y = 0;
        while (y < x.length) {
            if (y == 1) {
                System.out.print(String.format("%c %c ", x[y], z));

            } else {
                System.out.print(String.format("%c ", x[y]));

            }
            y++;

        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I'm still learning and sometimes i have a blackout on simple stuff. thanks one more